# Trying to burn a CD: "hdiutil: imageinfo failed - image not recognized"

Tags: macos, terminal, optical-drive

Using the Application Burn, I saved some music-CD's as image-file to the desktop as .iso, along with the right .isoinfo. Now I want to burn those images to empty CD's, but I get the following error when opening the image file:

`hdiutil: imageinfo failed - image not recognized`

This error is not directly related to Burn, because it gives this error when I try to open the image with DiskImageMounter (default on Mac) or when I do `hdiutil imageinfo image.iso` in the Terminal.

I have no idea why this is happening, and Googling didn't provide me with a solution. If someone knows how I can fix this it would be great.

I am running OS X El Capitan (10.11) on a Late 2011 15" MacBook Pro. The images come from several CD's, so it is not the case for one specific CD.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT //
I now ran the command in verbose, this is the output:

```
hdiutil imageinfo -verbose image.iso 
hdiutil: imageinfo: processing "image.iso"
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  0, score      100, CBSDBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  1, score    -1000, CBundleBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  2, score    -1000, CRAMBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  3, score      100, CCarbonBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  4, score    -1000, CDevBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  5, score    -1000, CCURLBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  6, score    -1000, CVectoredBackingStore
DIFileEncodingInstantiatorProbe: interface  0, score    -1000, CMacBinaryEncoding
DIFileEncodingInstantiatorProbe: interface  1, score    -1000, CAppleSingleEncoding
DIFileEncodingInstantiatorProbe: interface  2, score    -1000, CEncryptedEncoding
DIFileEncodingInstantiatorProbe: interface  0, score    -1000, CUDIFEncoding
DIFileEncodingInstantiatorProbe: interface  0, score    -1000, CSegmentedNDIFEncoding
DIFileEncodingInstantiatorProbe: interface  1, score    -1000, CSegmentedUDIFEncoding
DIFileEncodingInstantiatorProbe: interface  2, score    -1000, CSegmentedUDIFRawEncoding
DIDiskImageInstantiatorProbe: interface  0, score    -1000, CUDIFDiskImage
DIDiskImageInstantiatorProbe: interface  1, score        0, CSparseBundleDiskImage
DIDiskImageInstantiatorProbe: interface  2, score        0, CSparseDiskImage
CRawDiskImage: data fork length 0x00000000274E2DC0 (659434944) not a multiple of 512.
DIDiskImageInstantiatorProbe: interface  3, score     -100, CRawDiskImage
DIDiskImageInstantiatorProbe: interface  4, score        0, CDARTDiskImage
DIDiskImageInstantiatorProbe: interface  5, score        0, CDiskCopy42DiskImage
DIDiskImageInstantiatorProbe: interface  6, score        0, CNDIFDiskImage
DIDiskImageInstantiatorProbe: interface  8, score     -100, CShadowedDiskImage
DIDiskImageInstantiatorProbe: interface  9, score    -1000, CCFPlugInDiskImage
DIDiskImageInstantiatorProbe: interface 10, score     -100, CWrappedDiskImage
DIDiskImageNewWithBackingStore: probe fails to find appropriate CDiskImage class.
hdiutil: imageinfo: result: 110
hdiutil: imageinfo failed - image not recognized
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Image File created by Burn.app is a RAW Image and does not contain a recognizable filesystem that OS X understands and why `hdiutil` fails. It's also why an "Audio CD.isoInfo" file needs to be created, so the Burn.app can burn the image it created back to optical media (CD).

Since you created the Audio CD Image with the Burn.app then why don't you just use the Burn.app to burn the Audio CD Image to optical media (CD)?

[image: Audio CD.isoInfo]

[image: Audio CD.isoInfo - SuperDrive]

Comment: I did use Burn to write it back to a new CD, but I opened the iso file in Burn, not the isoinfo. I also tried dragging them both into burn, but as you say now I should have used the isoinfo in Burn. So that's for a next time. I gave up yesterday and used Toast to do the job.